# Magento email not working after product purchase

Tags: magento-1.7, email

I am developing an ecommerce magento website . But if someone purchase the product , he doesn't get an email with product purchase information ?
What could be the problem ?
Please help

Comment: Are you getting the email on new register?

Comment: I haven't checked it , i am informing you by doing this

Comment: No , i have registerd as user but i didnt get any email for that also

Comment: I guess it is some server side issue, please connect your server team on this

Comment: how to solve i if it is an server error .
Can i do it with doing some settings on my server ?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to (Web) development. You need to debug (usually a linear process), and you should also determine when a vendor can help you to debug.

Debug chain:

1. Can PHP send mail? There are several mail-with-PHP testing scripts out there; [here's one](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/how-can-i-test-php-mail-functionality).

   1. No: STOP. work with your host to determine the issue
   2. Yes: PROCEED to 2
2. Can Magento send email? There are several ways to test this in general. [Here's an extension which does this.](https://www.yireo.com/software/magento-extensions/emailtester)

   1. No: You need to find out why. This probably requires a developer's help.
   2. No: Is it really being sent but getting flagged as junk?
   3. No: Still might be a hosting issue.
   4. Yes: Problem Solved!

There are lots of nuances to this which involve other troubleshooting paths, but hopefully this is helpful.